# DataGrid sets Property but don't get value to change SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm having a weird problem in a Datagrid. I'm using WPF with DataBinding, I have a DataGrid, and 3 buttons in a Page - Save, Update, Cancel - and a lot of labels. These labels, when user clicks the Update Button, will enable editing mode to these labels.

While in edit mode, that user can't change SelectedIndex of that Grid (that's my problem).
I've tried to create a Property IsNotEditable, Binding to IsEnabled="" of that DataGrid, but if it's disabled, the current row is unselected.

I can't use that, because when user clicks Save, i'll save that Selected Row.
So... I've created another Property PlacasSelectedItem, and a 'Support' Property PlacasSelectedAux, with this code:

```
 public ConeSlab PlacasSelectedAux { get; set; }

    private ConeSlab placasSelectedItem;
    public ConeSlab PlacasSelectedItem
    {
        get { return placasSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (CurrentEditMode == EditMode.View)
            {
                placasSelectedItem = value;
                PlacasSelectedAux = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlacasSelectedItem");

                if (PlacasSelectedItem != null)
                    PlacaQuenteIsChecked = StringUtil.ConvertYesNoToBoolean(PlacasSelectedItem.Slab.InfHotSlab);
                else
                    PlacaQuenteIsChecked = false;

                ExibeLaminadorDestino();
            }
            else if (CurrentEditMode != EditMode.View)
            {
                // if isn't in ViewMode, and if user clicks in another Row, will force previously row to be selected.
                placasSelectedItem = PlacasSelectedAux;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlacasSelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, now the weird problem: It executes the code, I see the change in the code, but the SelectedIndex doesn't change! The Databinding doesn't work!

Here is my Binding:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PlacasSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have a editable datagrid and you select a row and put one of its cells in edit mode. Now according to you the problem is user is not allowed to change selection from that row to another row? Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. As Item on your grid can be a subject to change, more secure way to access your *row* (at this point), from UI to model, is to find a actually a row on the control. 
   You can try to use an extension method, something like this :

   ```
   public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRowFromGrid(this DataGrid myDataGrid)
   {

       return (DataGridRow)
          myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myDataGrid.SelectedItem);
   }
   ```
2. It seems to me (hope I right understand your app workflow) , that your data on row has to be binded to the model, so the user when changes a row content, it's up to `DataBinding` to take care of changing underneath linked model object, and after it, the only thing you will need actually, is to save your *model object*, *so no any UI access needed*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i forgot to tell something... I'm using MVVM, and I don't want to use code-behind, so, I need to do that with Properties. I think if i could block navigation into the Datagrid, it could solve the problem.

Comment: @gustavosg: may be it could enough to you just save the ROW where editing begin, using the code provided.

Comment: ok, problem solved. Into the xaml:
IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=IsEditing, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
this inverse the Boolean value to disable changing Datagrid row selection.

Comment: Used this method:
[ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(Boolean))]
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {
  return !(Boolean)value;
 }
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved. Into the xaml's Datagrid:

```
IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=IsEditing, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
```

Created a Static Resource:

```
   <Page.Resources>
    <ut:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />

   <Page.Resources>
```

This will inverse the Boolean value to disable changing Datagrid row selection, using this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert bool to !bool
/// </summary>
[ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(Boolean))]
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(Boolean)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now the user can't select any other row in the DataGrid!
Thanks for your help :)